# Magento 2 how to check if customer changes his password?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account

I'm using an observer that triggers every time customer edit it's account.
I'm using `customer_address_save_before` for some reason this event also triggers when I modify my email, name, or password from front end customer. 
How can I verify if the customer edit it's password? 
something like `$passwordOld = $customer->getOldPassword(); $passwordNew = $customer->getNewPassword();`

Of course this are just examples, the methods does not exist.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check/compare customer's old password and updated password value by below code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $encryptor;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    )
    {
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $currentPasswordHash = $this->getCurrentPasswordHash($customer->getEntityId());
        try{
            $newPasswordHash = $this->encryptor->encrypt("new password value");
            if($currentPasswordHash == $newPasswordHash){
                // password is same
                $this->_messageManager->addWarning(__("New Password is same as current password. Please choose another one"));
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            echo 'Error::'.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    private function getCurrentPasswordHash($customerId){
        $resource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $sql = "Select password_hash from customer_entity WHERE entity_id = ".$customerId;
        $hash = $connection->fetchOne($sql);
        return $hash;
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to use decrypt password values to compare and check, you can use below line of code in your observer.

```
$decrypt = $this->encryptor->decrypt("password hash");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hello, what value should I insert in $newPasswordHash = $this->encryptor->encrypt("new password value"); ? I cannot put manually the value of the password, because Customer will change it from front-end

Comment: You can get it from the customer observer event.

Comment: But how? what is the method from $customer that gives me the password or new hash?

Comment: Get post data from the request and pass the password value from the post data to the new password value.

Comment: your code is working, the only thing that I need to figure out is how to get the new password, I'm checking how to get the password from Create Account form.

Comment: Have you checked the post request data in the observer??? you can use php variable $_POST for check it.

Comment: I will give it a look, do you have an idea of what is the name of password field? like $_POST["password"], or when can I check for the form.phtml for editing account?

Comment: You can check the name of the field in the password change form in the account section. Also, you need not to check the form.phtml for editing account as we are handling this in our observer.

Comment: @Sumit I have try to update password but not checking properly old password with new password ?